# Open a pop up window and hide it when user clicks anywhere outside the pop up window

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I am trying to display a pop up window over the parent window in my java web application. When the user clicks on a link in parent window a pop up window must appear over the parent. In the pop up window user can select any value being fetched from database(hibernate). After that when user clicks "OK" button inside the pop up window or clicks anywhere outside the pop up or in parent window that pop up shall hide.

Comment: you can use [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox) for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper element that has a z-index superior to your parent window, but lower than your popup window.

addEventListener for "click" to that element.

If the target === that element, close the popup and remove the element itself.

That will handle your clicks "outside the popup".

The rest should be handled by your window's events.

**EDIT**

**styles**

```
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        #overlay {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
            z-index: 99;
        }

        #popup {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20%;
            height: 20%;
            top: 40%;
            left: 40%;
            background: rgb(220,220,220);
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            z-index: 100;
        }
```

**html**

```
<input id="popupbutton" type="button" value="pop me up" />
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
        document.getElementById('popupbutton').addEventListener('click', loadPopup, true);

        function loadPopup(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var overlay = document.createElement('div');
                overlay.id = 'overlay';
                overlay.addEventListener('click', closePopup, true);

            var popup = document.createElement('div');
                popup.id = 'popup';

            document.body.appendChild(overlay);
            document.body.appendChild(popup);

            function closePopup(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                // only close everything if click was on overlay
                if (e.target.id === 'overlay') {
                    document.body.removeChild(popup);
                    document.body.removeChild(overlay);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**EDIT 2**
Link to working JS fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/md063bfr/1/

Comment: Can you please show some working example or any references. Thanks

Comment: added working example code to my answer.
It's not the cleanest thing, but it's a proper demonstration for the current purpose.

Comment: My bad, my code worked in all but IE, I have fixed it to work in IE9+ and added a JS fiddle for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

you can use div.
ex-

```
<td> 
 <div align="center" id="show_sub" style="background-color:    pink;display:none;width:670px;height:370px;top:110px;overflow: auto;">
  your content here
</div>
</td>
```

then set display none->show in javascript function

```
function ShowDiv(){
            Popup.show('show_sub');
        }
```

thats all.
thanx.